# create array dynamic Laravel PHP

Tags: php, laravel

i want when Foreach my Data , For Loop Add Data to Resume Array , exmaple :

Source :

```
foreach($getusers as $val)    // 2record get data from bank But Just 1 record add to Array :(
        {
            $arr_data =array([
                'username'=>  $sec->dekey($val->user_username),
                'info' => $sec->dekey($val->user_info),
                'mobile' => $sec->dekey($val->user_phone),
                'code' => $sec->dekey($val->user_code),
                'jobside' => $val->user_jobside,
                'status' => $val->user_status,
                'datetime' => $val->datetime,
                'userid' => $val->id,
            ]);
        }
```

Export :
[{"username":"091584440004","info":"\u062d\u0627\u0646\u06cc\u0647 \u0631\u0648\u062d\u06cc","mobile":"09154479303","code":"091584440004","jobside":"EXPERT","status":"ACTIVE","datetime":"1399/08/13 - 19:26:37","userid":6}]

i want to :
[{"username":"091584440004", info ......]},[{"username":"0921538242",info  ......]}, ....

Thanks .

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting your array instead of adding to it.

To initialise an array, you do:

`$arr_data = []`

And to append to it:

`$arr_data[] = ['new' => 'entry'];`

In your example:

```
$arr_data = [];
foreach($getusers as $val) { 
    $arr_data[] = [
        'username'=> $sec->dekey($val->user_username), 
        'info' => $sec->dekey($val->user_info), 
        'mobile' => $sec->dekey($val->user_phone), 
        'code' => $sec->dekey($val->user_code), 
        'jobside' => $val->user_jobside, 
        'status' => $val->user_status, 
        'datetime' => $val->datetime,
        'userid' => $val->id,
    ]; 
}
```